# Problem with if statements within while loop

Tags: python, passwords, printf, python-3.8, with-statement

The code at line 7 works when 'Add' is typed. But the code at line 7 keeps repeating when 'View' prompt is entered. This is my password storing programe

```
import string

master_pass = input('Lost in Soul Sand be everything, but the KEY! \n')

while master_pass == 'Soul':
    action = input('Add/View Soul?').lower()

    if action == 'add':
        U = input('Soulname: ')
        P = input('Soul Sand: ')
        with open('sandvalley.txt','a') as f:
            f.write( U + '|' + P + '\n')
            print('Souls saw the light')

    if action == 'view':
        with open('sandvalley.txt','r') as narrate:
            narrate.readlines()
            for row in narrate:
                print(row)

    if action != 'add' or 'view':
        print('Soul has left the storm')
        break

print ('End')
```

Comment: `if action != 'add' or 'view':` does not mean the same as `if action not in ['add','view']:` - if you meant action is not one of 'add' or 'view' then what you have isn't doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> The code at line 7 works when 'Add' is typed. But the code at line 7 keeps repeating when 'View' prompt is entered.

since all options (`add`, `view`, and other strings) will not keep the program stay in the loop in my test and *line 7* is a blank line.
But I do know if you want to use the variable `action` to control the program, then `if action != 'add' or 'view:` is certainly not the guy you looking for.
What `if action != 'add' or 'view':` acutally does is `if (action != 'add') or ('view'):`, which means if the variable action is **NOT** `'add'` **OR** `'view'`, and the so-called [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is coming around. According to [doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KBsg.png), any string whose *length* is not *zero* is considered `True`, hence the conditional expression will always be `True` and the ending process will always be done.
If you want to fix it, `if action not in ['add', 'view']` will be good, but I will use

```py
if action == 'add':
    # do something
elif action == 'view':
    # do something
else:
    # end the program
```

instead, which is better IMO.

BTW, in Python 3.10+, *match-case* is introduced ([link to doc](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching)), and this kind of cases is definitely the best time to use it.

```py
match action:
    case 'add':
        # do something
    case 'view':
        # do something
    case _:
        # end the program
```

Give it a try.

Comment: thank you karasu! what does the " _" indicate in the match function?

Comment: @Mykl_007 It is called *wildcard* and `case _:` is the default situation handler, which is like the `else:` at the bottom of the if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

The .readlines() function RETURNS a value so you want to save in a variabl, insted of say narrate.readlines(), say narrate = narrate.redlines().
That should work. Let me known if it work i try it already and i think it works fine:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cffm.png)
[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0dhb.png)

Also you can add somthing like this:
[ForCodeRepeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIR9i.png)
this make your code repeat while your imput is != add and view.

The way you code putting action != 'add'or  'view' doesnt work because if you make the input "view" the condition  action != 'add'or  'view' will be true because "view" != add. And if your input is "add" the condition will be true again because "add" != "view.
That why you want to use and instead of or becaose you want that your code stops whenyour input isn´t one of them.

Another solution could be use elif:
[Elif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f2lh.png)

Because if the code won´t run if the option above is true.

Hope it helps u.